# How to pass a value from an anchor tag to a html code that's inside a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, popover

I have an anchor tag that opens a popover and the popover has an anchor tag itself, the latter generated with javascript. I need to pass a value from the first anchor tag to the second.

Popover code:

```
<a class="btn-opt btn-sm image-options" data-bs-container="body"
    data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="left"
    data-bs-html="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i></a>
```

Javascript:

```
var popString2 = "";
popString2 = popString2 + "<a href='#' class='options' id ='saveImage'>Save image<span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-regular fa-floppy-disk'></i></span></a>";

  $(".image-options").attr('data-bs-content', popString2);
```

I'm assigning `popString2` to the `data-bs-content` attribute of all anchor tags with the class `image-options` because I have several of them. The 'Save image' link in the javascript will trigger an image download.

When the popover is clicked, I need it to pass the image URL as the  `href` value to the anchor tag in the popString1 variable.

I'm loading the images with Flask. I could also load an `id` attribute value for each image, and then add that value somehow to the popover code so I can then pass it to the javascript. But I don't really know if that last part is possible.

[This screenshot will maybe help understand what I need to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLj1s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have an idea but I don't know javascript/jquery so I'm sure my code is wrong, mostly because it's not working.

The idea is to assign dynamically generated `id` attributes to both the img and the popover anchor tag. The `id` attribute for the anchor tag is the image id in the database, which I load with Flask, that way it's unique. The `img` tag id attribute is the same as the anchor tag's but adding "img" at the end. Ex. `<a id="1"></a>` / `<img id="1img">`. Then calling a javascript function from the anchor tag with `onclick` event.

My attempt at the javascript/jquery function is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.image-options').click(function() {
           var icon_id = $(this).attr('id');
           icon_id = "#" + icon_id
           img_id = icon_id + "img";
           the_url = $(img_id).attr('src');

           var popString2 = "";
           popString2 = popString2 + "<a href='" + the_url + "' class='options'>Save image <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-regular fa-floppy-disk'></i></span></a>";
           $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-content', popString2);

           var popString1 = "";
           popString1 = popString1 + "<a href='" + the_url + "' class='options' id ='addCollection'>Add to collection <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-solid fa-plus'></i></span></a>";
           $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-original-title', popString1);
        });
     });
```

HTML code:

```
<img class="card-img-top card-img-bottom thumb" data-bs-toggle="modal"
data-bs-target="#myModal" src="{{ url_for('static',filename=image[1]) }}" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'img' }}">

<a class="btn-opt btn-sm image-options" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-html="true" id="{{ image[0] }}" onclick="url_getter()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i></a>
```

Could this work? If so, what is wrong with my code?

UPDATE:

So I corrected my JQuery as far as I could and it almost works. The attributes are assigned successfully to the popover anchor tag, but when I click on it, the "Add to collection" link works but the "Save image" one doesn't. When I inspect the element, the `href` value is gone from its anchor.

Comment: Since no one has answered and I solved my original question , I'm gonna create a different question for this new issue I'm getting.